# "Clear" button necessary in request/query form?

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, user-centered-design, users

I have a book request form where user enters his user id details, no of books, no of pages delivery mode and other booking details(comes to around 5-6 input fields). It has Submit, Clear and Cancel Buttons. Is it necessary to keep clear button ??? will user expects for clear button?? Just because user makes mistake in 1 or 2 fields, we need to clear all?
also if in case every field needs correction(worst case) user can edit then and there itself?? any suggestion on this is welcome!!

Comment: Is your site responsive? You might want to consider a mobile pattern where deleting fields isn't as easy as it is on desktop.

Answer (score 2):

According to Jakob Nielson ( [Reset and Cancel Buttons](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/)), removing the clear button from the form will improve the usability of the application for the following reasons,

- It eliminates the possibility of a user clicking the reset/clear
  button by mistake.
- With only "Submit" visible, the user knows exactly what they have to
  do next. Having two or more buttons will force the user to spend a
  few seconds to decide which button is the one they want to click.
- Having an extra button means the user will have more options, which will require extra thinking from the user.

It also suggests that a **reset/clear button would be useful in a case where the same user will fill the same form multiple times**. That is if the form remembers data from the previous submission.

But that also depends on the nature of information that is being filled. If its easier to edit existing data than filling in new data then a reset/clear button is not required.

Comment: Thanx!! am in the same page...will consider that

Comment: Hm.... What if it wasn't a button where it visually competed? And what if the form was responsive? I think a clear button could be beneficial to the user via mobile to clear forms easily instead of go through every single field and click "delete" a thousand times to clear it out.

Comment: @Majo0od It would depend on the type/amount of information the user is entering. If the user is filling out a simple form, such as what op has mentioned, (User ID, No. Books, Delivery Mode) between editing and correcting the field the and there and looking for the clear button (which causes them to start again), the former is faster because less thinking is required. And also how often would someone want to clear the entire form when so little information has been added.

Comment: @Majo0od But if a large form which a user is most likely to refill again is auto completed (ex: editing billing information - 1. info was auto completed from another transaction , 2. user is very likely to change or edit the details the next time) then a clear as you mentioned is very useful.

Comment: I agree with those mentioned notes!